# rvest data scraping replacing missing html_node with NA

Tags: r, rvest

**Hi, Everyone!**

For quite a while I have been trying to scrape the data and somehow replace the missing html_nodes with NA or anything else. However, I have been unsuccessful.

Could anyone please help me to figure out how to do it? Or where to look at to understand how to do it?

My current code for the scraping is as follows:

```
library('rvest')
header_bind <- c()
page <- 0
price <- c()
ebay <- c()
runtime <- c()
pages <- 2
for (i in 1:pages) {


    page <- page + 1
    link <- paste("https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_320094?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1000&rt=nc&_from=R40&_pgn=",page, sep="")
    webpage <- read_html(link)


    #read the name of the item
    header <- html_nodes(webpage, ".s-item__title")
    header_Text <- html_text(header)

      header_bind <- rbind(header_bind,as.data.frame(header_Text))

    #i get the price
    prim_html <- html_nodes(webpage, ".s-item__price")
    text_prim <- html_text(prim_html)

      price <- rbind(price,as.data.frame(text_prim))

    #i get the (amount sold this is missing sometimes)
    runtime_html <- html_nodes(webpage, ".NEGATIVE")
    text_runtime <- html_text(runtime_html)

      runtime <- rbind(runtime,as.data.frame(text_runtime))

    #prints 0 so i know that it went throught the for(){}
    print(0)
}
```

*P.s. I know that it looks bad but I am learning every day how to code better.*

The code outputs 48 obs for price and the name of the product, however, when it comes to the quantity sold or remaining it gives me 43.

I tried to learn how others are doing it by looking at similar stack**overflow** posts, however, I somehow did not manage to grasp the idea of them.
I had the idea that I could use this function for the element that has the missing nodes but it did not seem to work:

```
text_runtime<- webpage %>% 
      html_nodes(".NEGATIVE") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      {if(length(.) == 0) NA else .}
```

*This function gives me 43 elements too and does not put any NA where the node is missing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first extract `.s-item__details` using `html_nodes` and from every node  extract `.NEGATIVE` or `.s-item__hotness` using `html_node` (without s).

```
library('rvest')

pages <- 1
page <- 0
output <- data.frame(header = character(), price = character(), runtime = character())
for (i in 1:pages) {

  page <- page + 1
  link <- paste("https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_320094?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1000&rt=nc&_from=R40&_pgn=",page, sep="")

  webpage <- read_html(link)


  #read the name of the item
  header <- html_nodes(webpage, ".s-item__title")
  header_text <- html_text(header)

  #i get the price
  prim_html <- html_nodes(webpage, ".s-item__price")
  text_prim <- html_text(prim_html)

  price <- rbind(price,as.data.frame(text_prim))

  #i get the (amount sold this is missing sometimes)

  item <- html_nodes(webpage, ".s-item__details")
  runtime_html <- html_node(item, ".s-item__hotness")
  text_runtime <- html_text(runtime_html)
  text_runtime[is.na(text_runtime)] <- "0"

  # combine
  out <- data.frame(header_text, text_prim, text_runtime)
  output <- rbind(output, out)

  #prints 0 so i know that it went throught the for(){}
  print(0)

}

output

output

#                                                                                  header_text          text_prim text_runtime
# 1                      Google Nexus 5X H791 32GB (FACTORY UNLOCKED) 5.2" HD - Mint Green LG              $44.88      42 sold
# 2                 Motorola Moto Z3 Play 32GB - Unlocked - Deep Indigo - Brand New - XT1929-4            $177.02   7 watching
# 3                                 LG V20 -Brand New - H915 - Unlocked - Ships Express Canada            $162.16   5 watching
# 4           Samsung Galaxy J3 Unlocked 5" 16GB GSM 4G LTE Android Smartphone Black SM-J320W8             $77.89         0
# 5  New ListingSamsung Galaxy A30s SM-A307GN/DS Dual Sim (FACTORY UNLOCKED) 6.4" 64GB 4GB RAM            $212.43         0
# ...
# ...
# 42                Black phone 2 - 32GB - Black (Unlocked) Smartphone (Rest of World Version)            $318.65   5 watching
# 43                                                                               Sagem MC939            $199.00         0
# 44                                                                        Nokia 6220 classic            $199.00         0
# 45   New ListingSmart Mini Wireless HD Dual WiFi Pocket Projector 2G RAM 16G ROM Android 7.1            $353.35         0
# 46                                                                                nokia 7260            $149.25         0
# 47                                                                                smartphone            $250.00         0
```